# Updating snapd on Raspberry Pi

Tags: packages

I'm using `Snapd` quite heavily, although I need to use some features available on newer versions of the `Snapd` manager. (see https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/wip-refresh-app-awareness/10736)

The latest available on Raspberry Pi OS (by simply apt install `snapd`) is 2.37, although that's kind of out of date now.

I have been unable to find anywhere how to update to a more recent version. Surely I can just add an updated repository somewhere and then re-apt install, but I'm unsure if there simply isn't a newer `Rpi` version.

Does anyone know how to upgrade to a newer version? I'm currently on the latest buster OS.

Comment: Buster comes with a suite of interoperable software versions. People adding incompatible versions often come to grief.

Comment: So in other words, just leave it were it is?

Answer (score 0):

Just install a newer core snap on top of your older snapd. See [snap on debian](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-debian)
I found the solution inside the snapcraft forum. [snapd outdated](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/try-to-update-snapd-and-refresh-the-core-snap/20725/2)